# Time Formatting? VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, date, time, format

I have been trying to find how to make something happen if I write the time format for the textbox without it being the current time.

So instead of this:
`If TextBox1.Text = Format(Now, "hh:mm") And TextBox2.Text = Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy") Or TextBox1.Text = Format(Now, "h:mm") And TextBox2.Text = Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy") Then`
I want it to just detect that there is a time format and date format and this can be any time and date, it just matters that it has a time and date format.

Thanks for your help,
TheVB10Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DateTime.TryParse():

```
    Dim dt As DateTime
    If DateTime.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, dt) Then
        Debug.Print("Pass")
    Else
        Debug.Print("Fail")
    End If
```

Comment: This code works but when I write want to write 1:20 because I put that it will show me a Msgbox, I write 1:2 and it immediately shows the msgbox but I want it to have the full 1:20 @Idle_Mind

Answer (score 0):

A different implementation of DateTime.TryParse. Will return True if valid, False if invalid.

```
If(DateTime.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Nothing), True, False)
```

Comment: Also this code works but I had to modify it to this 'If DateTime.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Nothing)' and now it works, Thanks @Dennis

Comment: This code works but when I write want to write 1:20 because I put that it will show me a Msgbox, I write 1:2 and it immediately shows the msgbox but I want it to have the full 1:20 @Dennis